# How to use TensorFlow's WALSMatrixFactorization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to use TensorFlow's WALSMatrixFactorization estimator, but I can't figure out how to use it. The fit method takes an input_fn as argument, but what should this function return? As input, I basically have a matrix, that I want factorized with the WALS method, but I can't find out how to pass this matrix to the fit function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer to this question check this [notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/ahybrid_fewer_vms/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/10_recommend/wals.ipynb) has a lot to offer on how to use WALSMatrixFactorization with TensorFlow.